# SxaLayout.cshtml head tag does not show metadata components for site page

Tags: sxa

I've created a page type in `Sitecore 10.2 SXA` and it contains a base template `Page`.

[image]

The page base template consists of all the metadata templates.

[image]

When I try viewing the user-defined page via `View page source` the metadata tags do not appear.

[image]

Using SxaLayout.cshtml

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

@foreach (string style in assetLinks.Styles)
{
    @Html.Raw(style)
}

@foreach (var include in includes.Head)
{
    @Html.Raw(include.HTML)
}
@Html.Sxa().VisitorIdentification()
@Html.Sxa().Placeholder("head")
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/assets/css/style.min.css" />
</head>
```

Any idea how do I resolve this?

Comment: did you publish your Sitecore changes ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the SXA meta renderings are located on the [Meta Partial Design](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/102/sitecore-experience-accelerator/the-metadata-partial-design.html). I'm assuming that you have created a new page template but forgot to add proper Page Design mapping:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I changed the designing for page to default and it worked.